# Javascript timezone from frontend

Tags: javascript, html, date, timezone, web-frontend

What would be the time zone by default when we take current date or time in javascript using Date() in frontend? Isn't the time zone from where the user access the page.

Comment: It's the current point in time of the entire globe, and logging it gives local time and the local timezone (unless changed in the system settings).

Comment: So you mean it depends on the local system's timezone. right?

Comment: Yes, but August 10 2021 10:00 UTC is exactly the same point in time as August 10 2021 12:00 GMT+2 so it really depends on the context and what your goal is.

Comment: Yes, the timezone is host dependent, but Date objects are based on a [time value](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) that is (more or less) UTC. The local timezone settings are used for values in the [*Date* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?milliseconds), to parse local timestamps and to output local date and time values (i.e. using the non–UTC methods like *getMonth* and *getHours* vs *getUTCMonth* and *getUTCHours*).